# Change input to TinyMCE on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm displaying a list of input fields, which looks like the code below. What I want to do is change the input to a `TinyMCE` window on `click()` or `hover()`. To do this I wrote the javascript below, but that isn't working obviously since they're not `<textarea`'s.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="first" class="input-field" value="test1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="second" class="input-field" value="test2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="third" class="input-field" value="test3"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="fourth" class="input-field" value="test4"/>
    </div>

    <!--This continues for some time-->

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="fiftyseventh" class="input-field" value="test57"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="fiftyeight" class="input-field" value="test58"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="fiftyninth" class="input-field" value="test59"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="sixtieth" class="input-field" value="test60"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("body").on("click", "input.input-field" function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", true, id);
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand("mceAddEditor", true, id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing issue is in your javascript code.

Please check this line-

```
$("body").on("click", "input.input-field" function() {
```

there is no "," (comma) after adding `input.input-field`. i should be there.

```
$("body").on("click", "input.input-field", function() {
```

and i have checked your all code is working fine.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gpeaab)

Comment: Man, it really sucks to have a comma be the problem after days of trying, must've read over that a hundred times. Anyway, thanks a lot!